# Terraform Resource does not have attribute for variable

Tags: terraform

Running Terraform 0.11.7 and getting the following error:

```
module.frontend_cfg.var.web_acl: Resource 'data.terraform_remote_state.waf' does not have attribute 'waf_nonprod_id' for variable 'data.terraform_remote_state.waf.waf_nonprod_id'
```

Below is the terraform file:

```
module "frontend_cfg"
{
    source        = "../../../../modules/s3_fe/developers"
    region        = "us-east-1"
    dev_shortname = "cfg"
    web_acl       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.waf.waf_nonprod_id}"
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "waf" {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    name = "../../../global/waf/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

The file which creates the tfstate file referenced above is below.  This file has had no issues building.

```
resource "aws_waf_web_acl" "waf_fe_nonprod"
{
    name        = "fe_nonprod_waf"
    metric_name = "fenonprodwaf"

    default_action
    {
        type = "ALLOW"
    }
}

output waf_nonprod_id
{
    value = "${aws_waf_web_acl.waf_fe_nonprod.id}"
}
```

I will spare the full output of the cloudfront file, however, the following covers the text:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "fe_distribution"
{
    web_acl_id          = "${var.web_acl}"
}
```

If I put the ID of the waf ID into the web_acl variable, it works just fine, so I suspect the issue is something to do with the way I am calling data.  This appears to match documentation though.

Answer (score 2):

Use path instead of name in terraform_remote_state,
https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "waf" {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "../../../global/waf/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

or

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "waf" {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "${path.module}/../../../global/waf/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

I tested it with terraform version 0.11.7 and 0.11.14

---

If you upgrade terraform to version 0.12.x, syntax using remote_state ouput has changed.
So change

```
web_acl       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.waf.waf_nonprod_id}"
```

to

```
web_acl       = data.terraform_remote_state.waf.outputs.waf_nonprod_id
```

or

```
web_acl       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.waf.outputs.waf_nonprod_id}"
```